# Time Series from spectrum

Tags: matlab, fft, time-series, spectrum, ifft

I am having a samll problem while converting a spectrum to  a time series. I have read many article sand I htink I am applying the right procedure but I do not get the right results. Could you help to find the error?

I have a time series like:
[image]

When I compute the spectrum I do: 
    %number of points
    nPoints=length(timeSeries);

```
%time interval
dt=time(2)-time(1);

%Fast Fourier transform
p=abs(fft(timeSeries))./(nPoints/2);

%power of positive frequencies
spectrum=p(1:(nPoints/2)).^2;

%frequency
dfFFT=1/tDur;
frequency=(1:nPoints)*dfFFT;
frequency=frequency(1:(nPoints)/2);

%plot spectrum
semilogy(frequency,spectrum); grid on;
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');
ylabel('Power Spectrum [N*m]^2/[Hz]');
title('SPD load signal');
```

And I obtain:

[image]

I think the spectrum is well computed. However now I need to go back and obtain a time series from this spectrum and I do:

```
df=frequency(2)-frequency(1);
ap = sqrt(2.*spectrum*df)';
%random number form -pi to pi    
epsilon=-pi + 2*pi*rand(1,length(ap));
%transform to time series
randomSeries=length(time).*real(ifft(pad(ap.*exp(epsilon.*i.*2.*pi),length(time))));
%Add the mean value
randomSeries=randomSeries+mean(timeSeries);
```

However, the plot looks like:

[image]

Where it is one order of magnitude lower than the original serie.
Any recommendation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (at least) two things going on here. The first is that you are throwing away information, and then substituting random numbers for that information.

The FFT of a real sequence is a sequence of complex numbers consisting of a real and imaginary part. Converting those numbers to polar form gives you magnitude and phase angle. You are capturing the magnitude part with `p=aps(fft(...))`, but you are not capturing the phase angle (which would involve `atan2(...)`). You are then making up random numbers (`epsilon=...`) and using those to replace the original numbers when you reconstruct your time-series. Also, as the FFT of a real sequence has a particular symmetry, substituting random numbers for the phase angle destroys that symmetry, which means that the IFFT will in general no longer be a real sequence, but a sequence of complex numbers - and again, you're only looking at the real portion of the IFFT, so you're throwing away information again. If this is an audio signal, the results may sound somewhat like the original (or they may be completely different), but the waveform definitely won't match...

The second issue is that in many implementations, `ifft(fft(...))` will scale the result by the number of points in the signal. There are several different ways to avoid that, with differing results, but sometimes more attractive in different scenarios, depending on what you are trying to do. You can either scale the `fft()` result before you do the `ifft()`, or scale the `ifft()` result at the end, or in some cases, I've even seen both being scaled by a factor of `sqrt(N)` - doing it twice has the end result of scaling the final result by `N`, but it is a bit less efficient since you do the scaling twice...

Comment: I understand your point. But could you put a small exmaple to show which step shall I do for the ifft. Can you use my previous code?